# Build and Train Quantized Neural Network using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, neural-network, quantization

I am new to quantization and would like to learn how to build and train quantized neural network using numpy only.

Would be really grateful if anyone could point me in the right direction.

I would like to learn it using numpy as I will have a better understanding of the how the network behaves and can play with intermediate values if necessary.

Thanks in advance.